# Multi tier mobile device support

Tags: android, iphone, html, webserver, wap

Trying to research the most effective way to create a mobile webapp that would support all levels of devices:

dumbest feature phones with WAP and xHTML support

Blackberries/Windows Phone/Touch "dumb" phones

Droid/iOS

Obviously there should be progressive enhancement but I am completely open to just have different logic for each device tier. What is your opinion for how to best approach this? Open to any technologies.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, questions on SO are programming related. Avoid questions that can result in debate. Read the SO usage guide for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Most phones support `J2ME`, even older phones. But you would not be able to use all phone services in the app. However, it would be better than website browsing ...